# Copy folder recursivly in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy the local folder "stuff" into the "staging" folder in ansible:

```
- name: Copy the ansible stuff
  copy:
    src: ./stuff
    dest: ./staging
```

This is the direcotry structure of suff:

```
  - stuff
      - foo
          - bar
              - file.txt
```

I am getting this error:

```
Destination directory ./staging/stuff/foo/bar does not exist"
```

The folder `staging` does exist! It seems it has problems copying the nested folders.

Why?

This does work:

```
- name: Copy the ansible stuff
  shell: "cp -r ./stuff ./staging/"
```

Comment: Try giving absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dgw is right. Your shell: "cp.." seems working just if you are running playbook to localhost.

Your original playbook gets erorr because the relative dest path (./staging)
If you set an absolute path it works. e.g.

```
- name: Copy the ansible stuff
  copy:
    src: ./stuff
    dest: /tmp/staging
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy uses the src from the central ansible host, not from the playhost. With your shell copy your are copying locally on the playhost.

Comment: True. In my case the host is the localhost, that is why i Can Test it with shell.